# SQL Self Join wo PK

Tags: sql

I have a transactions table that looks like this (simplified):

```
TranID|TranType|TranVal|TranCode
12|Add|10|NJ
135|Add|50|NJ
142|Substract|20|NJ
501|Add|415|PA
421|Substract|15|PA
```

I want to add the 'adds' and then subtract the 'subtracts', grouped by TranCode.

So final sum of NJ is: 40 and for PA is: 400.

Is this even possible considering there is no common key?

Comment: Addition and subtraction are commutative, which means that order doesn't matter : )

Answer (score 2):

Just use aggregation:

```
select trancode,
       sum(case when trantype = 'add' then tranval
                when trantype = 'subtract' then - tranval
           end)
from t
group by trancode;
```